# How can I use a custom ::marker for a list and preserve the horizontal spacing of the default marker?

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists, glyph

In the snippet below, I used `::marker` to change the marker of the list items. However the spacing is not exactly how I'd like it, as the marker goes too close to the text. Adding some space helps, but seems a workaround.

```css
.good > *::marker {
  content: '\2713';
}
.good.spaced > *::marker {
  content: '\2713  ';
}
```

```html
<ul class="good">
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
</ul>
<ul class="good spaced">
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
</ul>
```

---

In other words:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the padding-left property on the li to add spacing between the marker and the text.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding-left: .5rem;
}

li::marker {
  content: 'X';
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Apples</li>
<li>Oranges</li>
<li>Bananas</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Well, this still looks like the workaround.